# using Viewmodel in service class with UI

Tags: android, viewmodel

I am working on a custom keyboard app that uses Inputmethod service class and has the keyboard UI. As I have read on a comment in Github " ViewModel should be used closely with an Activity or a Fragment". https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/137#issuecomment-327854042
Does that mean we cannot use viewmodel in service class with UI like InputmethodService class and Why?

Comment: why would you want to use a viewmodel ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody to pass data between activity and service

Comment: services existed before view models, so is there no other way of doing it ?

Comment: of course, there are other ways, but services are easier no?